# remix compiler just won't end compiling

Tags: solidity, remix, compilation

I've just started my journy with etherium, so now I am trying to  get my first script complied. I tried starting with this project
https://github.com/san-lee-ai/simple_auction
But I could not get the solidity script compiled. Clicking on the compile button, on the http://remix.ethereum.org, just make the arrows near the "compile SimpleAuction.sol" just turn enlessly, over more than 24 hours.
I got it down to This code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SimpleAuction {
  uint public auctionStart;
  uint public biddingTime;
}
```

That compiles without any fuss, to this code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SimpleAuction {
   uint public auctionStart;
   uint public biddingTime;
   function SimpleAuction(
   ) {
       auctionStart = now;
   }
}
```

That never gets compiled. It just spins endlessly without throwing any error.
This is a trend: any code that doesn't contain a function, compiles in seconds, but when I add a function, compiling never ends.

What can I do, to get my code to compile with functions? I am using compiler version 4.1 (I tried others, with similar results), and EVM Version default (again, tried others with similar results).

I am using a local node (not sure it has anything to do with this, but I just started, so I'm trying to stick to what I read).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check your browser console. I get a "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error when trying to compile that code with 0.4.1. If I use 0.4.26, things work fine. In case you're not aware, 0.4.1 is over **3 years** old. Many compiler bugs have been fixed since then. Please use a recent version of the compiler. 0.5.11 is current, and 0.4.26 is the last 0.4.x version (in case you're trying to get old sample code to work that uses 0.4.x syntax).

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, and you're right. As this is a comment and not an answer, but you're upvoted in my heart :)